# The output as [2] [1,2] after deleting 1 but output is [2][2]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I need the output as `[2] [1,2]` after deleting 1 but the output is `[2][2]`:

```
def array_dup(n,obj)

  array= []
  for i in 1..n
   print array.push(obj)[i]
 end

 return array
end

print (array_dup(5,'hi'))
c = array_dup(5, [1,2])
puts
print c

c[0].delete(1)
puts c
print c

puts
```

The output should look like:

```
["hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi"]
[[2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```

But, instead it looks like:

```
["hi", "hi", "hi", "hi", "hi"]
[[1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]2
2
2
2
2
[[2], [2], [2], [2], [2]]
```

Comment: Please fix the indentation in your code. It makes it really difficult to help you as is.

Comment: I just fix it please check

Comment: I fixed it to make it more readable.

Comment: I understand what the OP is asking... can we reopen it please?

Comment: Here's an abbreviated answer, in case it isn't reopened: Simply change `push(obj)` to `push(obj.dup)`. In the first case, you are inserting references to the same object, when you really want them to be separate. It's a bit ironic that you named the method `array_dup` when `dup` is what you needed all along!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution, It may seems large but it is working:

```
test_array = []
c.flatten[1..-1].each_slice(2).to_a.reverse_each {|x| test_array << x.reverse!}
puts test_array
```

**Output:**

```
[[2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2], [1, 2]]
```